# do i need dynamic memory allocation here?

Tags: c

This topic seems confusing to me.. tried reading up on it in wikipedia, still don't get it.. here is my code…

```
#include <stdio.h>

main () {    
    char name[10];    
    int i=0;
    for (i=0;i<11;i++){
        scanf("%c",&name[i]);
        printf("%c",name[i]);
    }    
}
```

the thing is my program never exits until the boundary condition is satisfied (i=10).. I want the program to exit as soon as i type my string regardless if the boundary condition (i=10) is met or not! do I need dynamic memory allocation?

Comment: How should your program know when you are done typing your string? The only way of knowing with your current code is when the counter reaches the limit. When you press enter?

Comment: yes when i press enter it prints what i entered, but the loop never exits unless the number of characters reaches 10, that is i=10..

Comment: You declare `name` to be `10` characters long, so it contains items `name[0]` till `name[9]`. Don't let your loop to use `name[10]` – that is in fact beyond your array, so writing to it and printing from it causes an undefined behavior. Use `for (i=0;i<10;i++)` instead.

Comment: @Ciapan I agree with you on that point. That does not answer my original question tho.. when i run the program and i type for example "drool" it prints "drool" but continues asking for input.. how do i get it to print the output and exit the program? that is my question

Comment: I know that. But I can't help you anymore, until you find the answer to @Adam's question: 'How should your program know when you are done typing your string?' The program must receive *some* information that you finished. How should it know, whether the 'drool' is your word or it should expect 'drooling'? You asked 'do i need dynamic memory allocation here?' in first place and the answer to *that* question is simply 'no, you don't'. However if you want to know HOW to stop it reading, you should define first WHEN it should stop reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your code as below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
main () {    
char name[10];    
int i=0;
for (i=0;i<11;i++){
    scanf("%c",&name[i]);
    if(name[i] == '\n')
    return 0;
    printf("%c",name[i]);
}
```

Comment: Please try to explain how to manage dynamic memory in your answer. thanks.

Comment: For dynamic allocation you will have to modify your buffer declaration. like " char *name = malloc(10);memset(name,'\0',10);". include necessary header file.

Comment: scanf("%c",name+i);
 if(*(name+i) == '\n')
  break;
 }
 printf("%s",name);

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic allocation would not make a difference; what you need to do is count how many characters you have read, and stop reading them when you run out of space.  In this case switch `11` for `sizeof name`.

If you want to stop when they press Enter, you have to check and see if the character you just read was `\n`, and stop if it is.  It would also be smart to stop if the input gets closed (which will be indicated by `scanf`'s return value being `0` or negative).

In C there is no builtin function to allocate as much memory as needed for what the person types; you would have to write a function to do that yourself, or use someone else's function. There is a POSIX function called `getline` which does something similar.

Comment: i tried to insert while(scanf("%c",&name[i])!="\n"), that is the program should execute until it sees a newline.. but it complains that new.c:9: warning: comparison between pointer and integer

Comment: You have to check and see if **the character you just read** was `'\n'`.  Your code attempts to look at scanf's return value.  The character you just read is stored in `name[i]`, so you need to compare `name[i]` with `'\n'`.   You should also look at scanf's return value though. Read the documentation for scanf to see what its return value means (or read my post).

Answer (score 0):

You probably need dynamic memory allocation if you're unaware (at the time of writing the code) how much memory you will need. However, you could also allocate a static arbitrarily sized array instead.

If you're not sure how large `name` should be, you could:

a. Set a size limit and have the program respond accordingly when it is reached.

b. Dynamically allocate some memory and resize the allocation when it fills up.

I hope this helps.